# Diameter of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

How do you solve this question?

> The diameter of the graph $C_m$ $\times$ $C_n$ is?

Also what does $C_m$ $\times$ $P_n$ mean?
(Taking $m \geq 3, n\geq 3$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $C_m\times C_n$ denotes the [tensor product of the graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs) in question. Let $u,v\in V(C_m\times C_n)$, which are of the forms $v=(v_i, u_j)$ and $u=(v_k, u_{\ell})$ assuming $V(C_m)=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ and $V(C_n)=\{u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_m\}$.

Now by the definition of the tensor product, $uv\in E(C_m\times C_n)$ iff $(v_i,v_k)\in E(C_m)$ and $(u_j,u_{\ell})\in E(C_n)$.

You can imagine $C_m\times C_n$ as an $m$-times-$n$ grid with only diagonal (both diagonals) vertices connected. Clearly the diameter is then $\text{diam}(C_m\times C_n) = \max(\text{diam}(C_n), \text{diam}(C_m))$.

Comment: Can you give an example like what will be the diameter of the tensor product of C_11 and C_13?

Comment: Well, the diameter of $C_n$ is $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, so the diameter of the tensor product of the mentioned graphs equals $6$.